# Overflow of levels for factor columns of data frame in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Try this code

```
f <- factor(sample.int(1000, 100))
df <- data.frame(F = f)
View(df)
```

Now when you mouse over F column in the RStudio View() tab, it shows "factor with 1 levels". But when you look at the definition of f separately, it will have all levels. I have tried with different levels. It shows correctly until 64 levels after that it behaves weird. Please let me know how to fix this. I already tried "nmax" that has not effect.

Below code works correctly

```
f <- factor(sample.int(1000, 64))
df <- data.frame(F = f)
View(df)
```

Comment: `nlevels(f)` and `nlevels(df$F)` give `100` for both of the first cases and `64` for both of the second cases for me in plain old R outside of RStudio.

Comment: I am also getting `nlevels(df[["F"]])` equals `100` in RStudio.  The `View()` option in RStudio says only 1 level but that is probably just a limitation of the viewer since the underlying object clearly still is in tact.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. Check with the help of `levels()` and `str()`

```
  f <- factor(sample.int(1000, 100))
  df <- data.frame(F = f)

  levels(df$F)
  #   [1] "7"   "8"   "15"  "20"  "22"  "33"  "51"  "65"  "70"  "84"  "86"  "93" 
  #  [13] "98"  "134" "161" "164" "169" "170" "189" "200" "203" "215" "218" "223"
  #  [25] "234" "245" "249" "268" "279" "292" "296" "313" "328" "344" "347" "355"
  #  [37] "357" "363" "370" "376" "388" "392" "394" "397" "441" "449" "470" "487"
  #  [49] "493" "510" "520" "530" "546" "554" "565" "575" "577" "578" "579" "592"
  #  [61] "597" "602" "605" "616" "618" "621" "623" "638" "645" "646" "670" "681"
  #  [73] "694" "695" "716" "717" "723" "725" "734" "740" "759" "775" "793" "794"
  #  [85] "797" "818" "821" "825" "846" "851" "863" "865" "885" "888" "928" "951"
  #  [97] "958" "977" "993" "994"

  length(levels(df$F))
  # [1] 100

  str(df)
  # 'data.frame':   100 obs. of  1 variable:
  #  $ F: Factor w/ 100 levels "7","8","15","20",..: 45 80 34 21 74 92 76 78 47 43 ...

  View(df)

  df$F
  #   [1] 441 740 344 203 695 865 717 725 470 394 376 347 885 370 84  928 863 618 851 681 65  93  15  621 279 245 554 388
  #  [29] 449 134 565 888 825 623 223 292 170 670 793 392 723 161 249 397 487 794 7   22  994 602 33  357 215 977 86  577
  #  [57] 694 296 328 958 993 363 20  716 638 169 759 546 846 646 821 313 70  605 510 218 578 189 98  234 645 200 355 592
  #  [85] 164 818 597 51  734 8   268 951 575 616 579 530 493 520 797 775
  # 100 Levels: 7 8 15 20 22 33 51 65 70 84 86 93 98 134 161 164 169 170 189 200 203 215 218 223 234 245 249 268 ... 994
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an R bug but an RStudio bug. It's all correct looking at nlevels() or str() and checking the Environment pane in RStudio (it says Factor w/ 314 levels for me), but the one place it's wrong as you noted is when you mouse-over/tooltip over the column name in View() and it says "factor with 1 levels"

Someone has reported the bug as of Feb 2017 and RStudio is looking into it. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115001084508-Factor-levels-differ-in-view-mode-and-environment-tab?input_string=View()%20bug%20when%20viewing%20factors%20with%20%3E64%20levels